# Do Jmeter input records in DB when i do a HTTP Sampler test?

Tags: jmeter

For example If i test a Master web page for 100 users by inputting values , will the Master table be updated with the 100 records?

Does Jmeter insert records into Database when we a web page performance test?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is designed to store the data in the DB whenever someone enters the data in the UI, then , yes, when you do your performance test using JMeter, the data you had entered will also get stored in the DB.

JMeter does not store the data into the DB itself. Whatever the action you do on the website, JMeter records it & repeats for 100 different users (whatever the usercount you give). So, if you had recorded script correctly & it works fine, you should be able to see the data in your DB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vinoth. I have tried a scenario for a ADD transaction using the recording option in Jmeter and run it for 5 users. But , in my DB there is no records for the same. Please support